# Não apareço como colaboradora em um projeto que faço parte no Git

Tags: git, github

Estou realizando um trabalho para uma disciplina com meus colegas. Consigo fazer pull e commits, entretanto,eu não apareço como contribuidora do projeto, não mostrando meu gráfico.Meus colegas só conseguem ver que eu fiz commits. Eu apareço como uma pessoa do [repositório](https://github.com/Geventos/projetogeventos), mas não apareço como contribuidora. Consigo visualizar tudo que meus colegas fazem. Quando o projeto iniciou eu aceitei o convite para fazer parte do projeto. O que pode ta rolando?

Comment: Vocês já tentaram ir nas configurações do projeto, em contribuidores/colaboradores e adicionar um novo contribuidor/colaborador?

Comment: Já tentei, mas também continua dando errado.

Answer (score 2):

Realmente você faz parte dos commits. Pede para realizarem o processo de inserção de colaborador novamente com o seu nome do GitHub. Realize a confirmação e pelo e-mail, e verifique novamente se foi adicionada como colaboradora. Basicamente é um processo simples e não vejo como isso daria errado.
[image: Print histórico commits]

**Verifica também se sua conta do GitHub está confirmada.**

Comment: Bruno, fiz o que me recomendastes, mas continuou com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

O GitHub identifica pelo e-mail do autor do commit. Rode no seu terminal:

```
git config --list
```

Veja se no output desse comando tem o seu e-mail, e qual está configurado. Esse precisa ser o mesmo e-mail que está no seu cadastro do GitHub. Se não for, você pode [adicionar um e-mail à sua conta do GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account/).

Se infelizmente você não encontrou seu e-mail no output do comando, você fez os commits sem um e-mail específico. Para corrigir isso você precisará fazer um `rebase --interactive` alterando todos os commits, adicionando seu e-mail ao autor do commit, e depois fazer um `push --force-with-lease`. Não recomendo que faça isso, pois tem grandes chances de dar errado, ainda mais por fazer um push forçado.

Comment: O que é esse `--force-with-lease`? Eu só conhecia o `-f`/`--force` ; se achar digno, posso abrir uma questão específica sobre isso

Comment: O `--force-with-lease` só faz o `push` se no remote não houver nenhum commit depois do histórico do repo local. Entendeu +/-?

Comment: entendi perfeitamente. Muito grato